# Issue making React-Komposer Reactive with multiple subscriptions

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am using meteor chef base and I'm having an issue with reactivity using react-komposer. I have a subscription call that takes ids from the url (lectureId, courseId) to first look for (and create if needed) a userLecture document with those ids and a currentQuestion field that it uses to get the current Question subscription. I later update that currentQuestion id but the question subscription doesn't update until a hard page refresh. How can I make that subscription reactive when the inputs aren't actually changing?

```
const composer = (params, onData) => {
  let subscription = Meteor.subscribe('questionFromSlugs', params.courseSlug, params.lectureSlug);
  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const question = Questions.findOne();
    const userLecture = UserLecture.findOne();

    onData(null, { question });
  }
};
export default composeWithTracker(composer, Loading)(QuizQuestion);
```

This is the meteor subscription:

```
Meteor.publish('questionFromSlugs', function(courseSlug, lectureSlug){
  check(courseSlug, String);
  check(lectureSlug, String);
  check(this.userId, String);
  let user  = this.userId;
  let lecture = Lectures.findOne({courseSlug: courseSlug, slug: lectureSlug});
  let course = Courses.findOne({slug: courseSlug});

  if (lecture != null && course != null) {

    var thisLectureScore = UserLecture.find({
      userId: user,
      lectureId: lecture._id
    }).count();

    if (thisLectureScore == 0){
      UserLecture.insert({
        userId: user,
        courseId: course._id,
        lectureId: lecture._id,
        lectureScore: 0,
        currentLevel: 1
      });
    }

    let userLecture = UserLecture.findOne({
      userId: user,
      courseId: course._id,
      lectureId: lecture._id
    });

    if (userLecture != null){
      return [
        Questions.find({_id: userLecture.currentQuestionId}),
        UserLecture.find({
          userId: user,
          courseId: course._id,
          lectureId: lecture._id
        })
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that it doesn't change? I had similar problem. It was hidden in how I was populating the view. What ui framework are you using? I think react. Please provide me with the view and I think I know the solution for your problem.